# HD: re-partition HD to fix bad partition while keeping the good one

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

Disk 2 has two partitions: a 25 GB healthy OEM partition and a 446 GB partition which cannot be formatted and doesn't show up in the top portion of Disk Manager.

Possible to use DISKPART to re-partition that bad partition while keeping the good, OEM partition?

If I select disk 2 and issue the command "clean", both partitions will be gone.

This is Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the step where you select the bad partition.
I would try to format the bad one first instead of attempting to delete and re-add it (via the clean command).

If you can't see the bad partition after `select disk <x>` and `list partition` then  DISKPART probably won't do it for you.

You will either need to load a better partition program (many are free) or use a linux live cd and use a disk utility on it.  Also.. see HIREN'S BOOTCD.

Comment: I went ahead to clean the disk and format it. After the process was 100% complete, there was a error message saying parameter incorrect. Now, the disk 2 is gone. Diskpart only lists disk 0 and 1.

Comment: Windows 10 reported an s.m.a.r.t. fault on the drive. I'll buy a replacement drive.